# Mocking File object argument in constructor to use inputstream

Tags: java, file, memory

I have an class, that I cannot modify, and this class contains one constructor which requires a java.io.File. I already have the information loaded from a different source and currently it is in memory. So I want to know if there is a way to mock the java.io.File object in such a way that is uses the information that is already in memory. I know I could first store the information from memory to disk, but I don't like that extra step.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

A `File` object doesn't not contain the *data* of the file, it's more or less a class that describes a file or folder just by its name (path).

`File` is not final, so you could extend it and provide a custom implementation - but, that doesn't help, because unlike Sockets, a `File` instance can't return an input or outputstream. A `File` is *used* by a reader, writer or stream class to just get the path for a file to read/write data through disk based IO. So mocking a `File` will not help.

You'd have to pass an input stream to the other class that provides the data from your memory source. Only chance to look at the API or, second idea: check if you can do something with reflection. Maybe you're lucky and the class has an inputstream field and maybe you're lucky again and it's enough to just set you're own, custom inputstream instance.